# How to run an SQL Update string from bash script with parameter?

Tags: sql, bash, postgresql, command-line, command-line-arguments

I would like to be able to update a database field by simply running a script with the new value as a parameter.

`ie>   ./update.sh newvalue`

and have it run an sql with the "newvalue" updating the cell.

Currently I open the database connection and paste in this sql to do the update.

```
UPDATE modules_config_x_roomtypes SET value = 'newvalue' WHERE modules_config_id = (SELECT id FROM modules_config WHERE module_id = (SELECT id FROM modules WHERE name = 'system') AND name = 'theme');
```

Comment: Have you checked Postgres documentation for `psql`? Here:http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-psql.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something simple like this seems like it'd work unless I'm misunderstanding the need.  Note I don't have psql so can't give you an exact solution but instead a guide.

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ $# -lt 1 ]
  then
    echo "USAGE: ./update.sh [newvalue]"
    echo "       [newvalue] represents the new value to insert into the DB."
    exit
fi

NEWVAL=$(echo $1 | sed "s/'/\\\'/g")
SQL="UPDATE modules_config_x_roomtypes SET value = '"$NEWVAL"' WHERE modules_config_id = (SELECT id FROM modules_config WHERE module_id = (SELECT id FROM modules WHERE name = 'system') AND name = 'theme');"
echo "$SQL" | mysql --user=user --password=password
```

This first makes sure you've got an argument, then escapes any single quotes in it so  it doesn't break the SQL statement, then echo's the SQL to mysql.  You'll have to modify the user and pass as req'd or source them from some other file.

If you need to insert a blank "" would work as the arg but this doesn't handle null.

You'll probably also want to add a check for sqls exit code to make sure the update took cleanly. That'd just be some simple if's with $?, but since that is not exactly in the context of the question I'll leave that as an exercise for you to complete.

I'm not running psql so I can't say the exact arguments needed for this to work there, but from the man page you can give the option -c to specify a commmand to run, so you'd probably replace the echo to mysql with that, and you'll also have to handle letting the script connect to the DB, but there are plenty of Q's on here around that.

Comment: awesome thank you @zzevannn, this worked great with psql, i just added the db info to the end

 `echo "$SQL" | psql wrkdb -U postgres`